# Analysis of complex transcendental inequalities

Tags: inequality, transcendental-equations, nonlinear-analysis

There is an inequality of the following form:
$(1/(w^2T^2))$ * $(w^2/(w^2T^2+1))$ * $(k^2/(w^2T^2+1)^2)$
Suppose it is necessary that this inequality be strictly < $m$.
Is it possible to determine the value $w$, at which the inequality is satisfied, by analyzing each of the factors separately?

Comment: Isn't it $$\frac{w^2k^2}{w^2T^2(w^2T^2+1)^3}<m$$?

Comment: Yes that's right! But, I did not just divide them into factors. I would like to know if it is possible, by analyzing each of the factors separately, to solve this inequality for $w$

Comment: The fact is that such factors can be not 3, but 5-8, for example, and I don’t know how to solve inequalities with such a order of transient equation.

Comment: I strive to simplify the solution of such problems.

Comment: It is a rational inequation for $w$. It gives a polynomial inequation for $w$. At first, you should solve the equation.

Comment: Is it possible to solve this equation by analyzing each of the factors separately?

Comment: I expect, that, in general, not.